# trying to freeze the left column

Tags: css, html

I would like the left column fixed when I scroll to the right.

Here is my code, thanks.
    
    
    
    css table

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function()
{
    //alert("testme");
    //$('#addScroll').jScrollPane();
    //$('#addScroll').scrollTo(150, 800 );
});


function show() {
    //alert("test");
    var shDiv = document.getElementById("thisOne").style.display;
    if(shDiv == "none")
    {
        document.getElementById("thisOne").style.display='block';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("thisOne").style.display='none';
    }



//document.getElementById("noe").style.display='none';

}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.container {
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
  width: 1560px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

* html .container {
  width: 762px;
}

.header {
  width: 1560px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.header ul {
  list-style: none
}

.header ul li {
  width: 150px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 2px;
}

* html .header ul li {
  width: 151px;
}

.data {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.subColumn {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.subData {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

* html .data {
  width: 152px;
}

.rowodd,.roweven {
  position: relative;
  width: 1560px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.roweven {
  background-color: #D1DCE9;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll">
<div class="container clearfix"> 
  <div class="header clearfix">
  <ul>
  <li>&nbsp</li>
  <li>QMPlus</li>
  <li>WHAT</li>
  <li>ICFWiz</li>
  <li>QM</li>
  <li>ToolBar</li>
  <li>DIBWiz</li>
  <li>RZWiz</li>
  <li>ARCH</li>
  <li>ToolBar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden">
  <div class="rowodd clearfix">
    <div class="data">
      <p>Total <a href="#" onclick="show();">+</a></p>
      <div class="roweven clearfix" id="thisOne" style="display:none">
        <div class="subColumn">
            Area 1
        </div>
        <div class="subData"><p>Netflix</p></div>
        <div class="subData"><p>BlockBuster</p></div>
        <div class="subData"><p>Vudu</p></div>
        <div class="subData"><p>Cine</p></div>
        <div class="subData"><p>PS3</p></div>
        <div class="subData"><p>boxee</p></div>
        <div class="subData"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    enter code here<div class="subData"><p>PS3</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data"><p>Boxee</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>24</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>45</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>boxee</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="roweven clearfix">
    <div class="data">
      <p>Chicago</p>

    </div>
    <div class="data"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>3</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>test</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>place</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>boxee</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowodd clearfix">
    <div class="data">
      <p>New York</p>

    </div>
    <div class="data"><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>0</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>why</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>google</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>boxee</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowodd clearfix">
    <div class="data">
      <p>Atlanta</p>

    </div>
    <div class="data"><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>0</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>where</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>go</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>boxee</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowodd clearfix">
    <div class="data">
      <p>Boston</p>

    </div>
    <div class="data"><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>0</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>test1</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>play</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>boxee</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowodd clearfix">
    <div class="data">
      <p>Phil</p>

    </div>
    <div class="data"><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>0</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>xbox</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>boxee</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>boxee</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>AppleTv</p></div>
    <div class="data"><p>PS3</p></div>

  </div>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are kidding me?!  Just go away...

Comment: I'd recommend scaling this down into a simplified example and then ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks, although I didn't do much beyond add code formatting (@Noe, put 4 spaces at the beginning of line for code formatting)

Comment: When you edit the question, you should see some instruction at the right hand side.  In the section "How to Format" it says to "indent code by 4 spaces".  I'll let you do that, because you pasted so much code.  Maybe you could cut the code down, too, to just the pieces that are poignant.  For example, the DOCTYPE element is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

```
 position:fixed;
```

Comment: Lol, nice and short. But seriously, yes, this sounds like what Noe needs. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work in IE6, and therefore don't want to use position:fixed, you should consider using the jquery plugin scrollFollow. You can find it here:

http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/

Good luck!